# Flutter adding widgets inside Positioned and getting BoxConstraints forces an infinite width. error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in this sample code i'm trying to adding some widgets such as `Column`, `ListView` inside `Positioned` parent widget but i get below error mostly:

> BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rect_getter/rect_getter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Overlay Menu',
      home: Sample(),
    );
  }
}

class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top:10.0,
              child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  'aaaa',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        menuItems[index],
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.assessment,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: menuItems.length,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify a specific width and height for the Positioned Widget:

```
     Positioned(
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        child: ...
      )
```